# Acessing properties of an object with initializers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this code:

```
public class TopTen
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ShortDesc { get; set; }
    public string LongDesc { get; set; }
    public Image Photo { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string ImgUrl { get; set; }
    public string AlterText { get; set; }
}
```

I can do like this to assign values:

```
new topten()
{
/*
     here I can access and give values to my properties. BUT i cant
     access and give values to the properties in my `Image` class.
     This is a problem because I would like to upload the new object as a json-file.
     So how do I access the properties in `Image`?
*/
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var x = new TopTen
{
    Id = 1,
    Photo = new Image
    {
       ImgUrl = "pic.jpg",
       AlterText = "This is a picture"
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly!